# ASP Net Core Auth - RedirectToAction back to Target Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

In an ASP.NET Core Rest API project, I have set up custom authentication, and I can annotate Controller Actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute, which redirects unauthorized requests back to my AuthController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ResponseController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Repository.GetResponse(id), Formatting.Indented);
    }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MetaController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Repository.GetMeta(id), Formatting.Indented);
    }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    UserManager _userManager;
    public AuthController(UserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<string> LogIn()
    {
        try
        {
            //authenticate
            var username = Request.Headers["username"];
            var password = Request.Headers["pass"];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                throw new Exception("Authentication Exception: Missing Username or Password");

            Task.Run(async () => {
                await _userManager.SignInAsync(this.HttpContext, username, password);
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return RedirectToAction("Search", "Home", null);
            //^^^ How to send back to intended action?^^^
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return AuthError();
        }
    }
}
```

This works, except how do I use the `RedirectToAction` method to return back to the intended controller (`MetaController` or `ResponseController`, in this case)? (the one with the method marked `[Authorize]`, which put us into this authentication controller to begin with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use returnUrl parameter, like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(string returnUrl = null)
{
    try
    {
        //authenticate
        var username = Request.Headers["username"];
        var password = Request.Headers["pass"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new Exception("Authentication Exception: Missing Username or Password");

        await _userManager.SignInAsync(this.HttpContext, username, password);
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Search", "Home", null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new {error = "Authentication Failed"});
    }
}
```

I also fix async/await for controller's action. You need use `async Task<ActionResult>` insted of your `ActionResult<string>`

Comment: Excellent answer and works out of the box, except my AuthError() method return ActionResult<string> (a json formatted error string). How do I keep this if the return type of Login(returnUrl) is ActionResult or Task<ActionResult>?

Comment: Can you provide `AuthError` method?

Comment: Simplified for brevity: `ActionResult<string> AuthError() { return "{ \"error\": \"Authentication Failed\" }"; }`

Comment: I think you can use `BadRequest(...)` that return 400 http code or use `Ok(...)` with the same error-object if you need to retrun 200 http code. I'm already edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirection, create your own attribute inheriting from the `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the `OnAuthorization` method. That way you don't have to worry about redirection.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the override `OnAuthorization` method?